# Fake Server with Sinon in Ember

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, sinon

I want to test my controller, which makes an ajax call to my backend. Therefor I want to use jasmine and sinon. Ffor faking my backend server with sinon I tried something like this:

```
describe("fake server", function() {
 var server;

 beforeEach(function() {
    this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    this.server.restore();
  });

 it("calls callback with deserialized data", function () {
    var callback = sinon.spy();

    this.server.respondWith("GET", "/comments/1",
    [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      '{"comment":{"id":1,"title":"ducks and ducks"}}']);

    commentController = App.CommentController.create();

    //commentController.bind('getComment', callback);

    commentController.getComment(); 

    this.server.respond(); 

    expect(callback.called).toBeTruthy();
    expect(callback.getCall(0).args[0].attributes)
      .toEqual({
        id: "1",
        title: "ducks and ducks"
      });
  });
});
```

My controller looks like this:

```
 App.CommentController = Ember.Controller.extend({
      getComment: function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://myapi/comments/' + id,
          //...
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            this.set("error",true);
            //do something
          },
          success: function(data) {
            this.set("error",false);
            //do something else
          }
        });
      }
  });
```

Can someone tell me how I get running this?

Comment: Have you considered using Ember Data's FixtureAdapter instead? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/4HFLw/) I forked (using revision 10) so you can see how it works

Comment: Yes I did. But even there I have async backend calls which I would like to mock with sinon fake server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.server.respondWith("GET", "http://myapi.com/comments/1",
[200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  '{"comment":{"id":1,"title":"ducks and ducks"}}']);
```

In my case the url should be absolute.